# Question about using Gauss' Law with a surface at infinity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

While doing homework, I came across a situation where I tried to make this argument: For a finite distribution of charges, I know that the electric field drops off to zero at infinity. So therefore, if I take a surface A which encloses these charges, and I let this surface grow to infinity, then with

$$
\oint_{A} \vec{E}\cdotp d\vec{a} = \frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_{0}}  
$$

it'd follow that the enclosed charge is zero because the left-hand side is zero.

I know this is wrong, but I actually can't think of an exact reason why. Because I've seen arguments where the integration is taken over a surface at infinity and a sensible result does come out, like when finding the energy of an electrostatic field (this happens in the textbook Introduction to Electrodynamics by David Griffiths).

My argument would seem to "make sense" if the surface was enclosing a dipole - so I'm thinking, am I only allowed to integrate over a surface at infinity and say "that integral is zero because the field is zero at infinity" only if the first order terms of the field are zero, or some other subtlety like that? And why? What's going on?

Comment: Think of the integral as a sum, when you let the surface go to infinity the number of terms summed grows without bound even as the thing summed vanishes. The processes cancel out. I'll leave one of our more theoretical folks to make that argument rigorous. Or perhaps this should be migrated to Math SE.

Comment: E goes down, but the total area goes up as $r^2$. The field must fall off faster than that to get zero. Dipole fields fall as $1/r^3$ so they give zero.

Comment: Ok, I think it makes sense that I should have the field fall off faster than the area. Though, if my question is more appropriate as for the math SE, how should I go about reposting/moving (?) it? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Either a mod or a gang of high-rep users could migrate it to Math. If you want that just ask. If you don't care either way then wait and see.

Comment: @Cal When you claim the field falls off faster than the area grows, then you are claiming the charge enclosed is zero. If you assume the charge enclosed is zero, then the charge enclosed is  zero. And when it isn't zero, the field does *not* fall off faster than the area grows. Pick one, and move on with your life.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the mathematical rigorousness to answer well the question but here's a thought.

The left hand side is not 0. Take a point charge for simplicity, in this case $\vec E$ and $d \vec a$ are orthogonal and so the integral is worth $E\cdot A$. Although it is true that $\vec E$ tends to $\vec 0$ for $r \to \infty$, $A$ tends to infinity. And so you cannot conclude that the integral vanishes because "$0 \cdot \infty$" is undetermined. In fact what really happens here is that the product stays constant and is equal to $q/\varepsilon _0$ as it should.

Answer (score 0):

How to compute a surface integral on a surface at infinity?

Don't take a limit of the integrand at infinity and then try to take an integral of that.

Keep in mind that an integral is a limit and the order you take limits matters. So you need to take integrals on compact surfaces, get your results and then take the limit of those results.

So the key is to *read* it a limit of integrals on surfaces in the limit the surfaces go to infinity.

As the surface goes to infinity, what do the integrals approach.

This is just entirely different than trying to evaluate the integrand at a limit and then scratch your head about how to integrate that. Because you'd then need a surface at infinity on which to integrate.

When someone talks about a surface at infinity they mean a limit of surface integrals.